# Read values from a different plist file in objective - c

Tags: objective-c, plist

I have to read a value from a plist that is present in ~/Library/Preferences in my objective - c Code.

How should i achieve this ?

Comment: Depends if it's a dictionary or a array at top level, but `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` or `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *path =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Preferences"];
NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"]  stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"]];
```

by this you get full plist as dictionary